# iTunes video black screen until select computer output

Tags: video, osx-snow-leopard, itunes

I don't remember this happening before, but now whenever I play any video in iTunes (podcast video, movie, TV show, iTunes extras stuff but the menus work) it just shows a black screen with the sound playing. If I stop it, select "Computer" in the little output control on the iTunes video control panel that pops up, then play again, it works fine.

What the heck?

Tried rebooting, updating, with and without external monitor.

OSX 10.6.6

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue! I will file a bug report, but the whole 10.6.6 update has been a total nightmare for me.